# Is there a way to retrieve row IDs where a column containing ALL values specified (Oracle Database)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows:

```
| Col1 | Col2       |
| ---- | ---------- |
| A    | val1       |
| A    | val2       |
| B    | val1       |
| C    | val3       |
```

I want to receive those values of `Col1` , which contains rows with BOTH `val1` AND `val2` as `Col2` (i.e. `A`). I know I can do this using `INTERSECT`, but that requires me to piece in multiple clauses together. Is there a way to do this using a single clause, such as something like an `IN ALL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming you have no duplicates:

```
select col1
from t
where col2 in (val1, val2)
group by col1
having count(*) = 2;
```

The `2` matches the number of items in the list.

Comment: `having min() <> max()` is sufficient and doesn't care about duplicates

Comment: @astentx . . . It doesn't generalize to more than two values, which this form does.  Of course, `having count(distinct col2) = 2` does generalize, but there is probably no reason to use `distinct` because tables usually don't have duplicate rows.